# nginx multiple limit request through map getting error - zero size shared memory zone "$tsl_limit_req_zone"

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

nginx.conf file

```
# Define rate limit zones
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=tsl:10m rate=20r/s;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=tsl-limit-req:10m rate=10r/m;

map $request_method $tsl_limit_req_zone {
    default     "tsl";
    GET         "tsl";
    POST        "tsl-limit-req";
    PUT         "tsl-limit-req";
    DELETE      "tsl-limit-req";
}

server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             localhost;
    client_max_body_size    200M;

    keepalive_timeout 0;
    
    # Disable server tokens only for this project
    server_tokens off;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/tsl-web;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /api {

        limit_req zone=$tsl_limit_req_zone burst=5 nodelay;

        proxy_pass nginx_http_proxy_pass;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # error_page  404              /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the nginx static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

error log

2024/03/13 10:32:57 [emerg] 8#8: zero size shared memory zone "$tsl_limit_req_zone"
nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "$tsl_limit_req_zone"
2024/03/13 10:32:58 [emerg] 9#9: zero size shared memory zone "$tsl_limit_req_zone"
nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "$tsl_limit_req_zone"
2024/03/13 10:33:00 [emerg] 9#9: zero size shared memory zone "$tsl_limit_req_zone"
nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "$tsl_limit_req_zone"

map function not working properly, that's why we are getting this error

Don't know what i am exactly make mistake, help me anyone thanks for in advance